# RecyclerView doesnt execute methods

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

After long research and try-and-errors I just can't wrap my head around why my `getItemCount()` doesn't get called, after my `RecyclerView` was created.

To introduce you into my code, a short explanation:

Basically, the first creation of my `RecyclerView` is empty, because the data is not ready but the fragment get's created with the `setContentView()` call. Then the second round begins, creates a Loader which fetches Data from an URL. After that, a new `NewsEntryFragment` gets created, which, in return, creates a new `RecyclerViewAdapter`, that should be shown within my `SpinnerActivity`.

I debugged a few times and sorted out some things:

- `getItemCount()` gets called 4 times in the first round, the empty round. It always returns 0, but that's fine because there's no data anyways.
- `getItemCount()` never gets called in the second round, where the data finally is ready and should be displayed.
- `onBindViewHolder()` doesn't get called a single time, whether in the first, nor in the second round.

Maybe, it's because the `RecyclerView` gets created two times? And the second time, things don't get called? I don't know.. that's why I need your help :)

Anyway, here's my code:

**SpinnerActivity.java**

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<NewsEntry>>, 
NewsEntryFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener,
NewsEntryFragment.DataInterface {

final String GUARDIAN_BASE_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=xxx";
final String PARAM_SORT = "order-by";
final String PARAM_QUERY = "q";
final String PARAM_CURRENT_PAGE = "page";
final String PARAM_SHOW_FIELDS = "show-fields";  

private String mQuery;
public URL mRequestURL = null;
LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
private ArrayList<NewsEntry> mNewsEntries = new ArrayList<>();

private final String TAG = "MY";


ArrayList<String> mTopicsList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }

    populateSpinner();




}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    mQuery = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    buildQuery();
    loaderManager.destroyLoader(0);
    Loader loader = loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

@Override
public Loader<List<NewsEntry>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i("MY", "onCreateLoader: Loader created");
    return new NewsLoader(this, mRequestURL);

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<NewsEntry>> loader, 
List<NewsEntry> fetchedNewsEntries) {
    mNewsEntries.addAll(fetchedNewsEntries);
    //NewsEntryFragment fragment = (NewsEntryFragment) fragmentManager
    .findFragmentById(R.id.headlines_fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(new NewsEntryFragment(), ""+mQuery+" used for this Fragment")
    .commit();
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished: " + mQuery + " used for this Fragment");


}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<NewsEntry>> loader) {
}

@Override
public void onListFragmentInteraction(NewsEntry item) {

}


    private void populateSpinner(){

    ArrayList<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();

    topics.add("Android");
    topics.add("Android");
    topics.add("Test 3");

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> topicsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, topics);
    topicsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
    spinner.setAdapter(topicsAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

}
```

**NewsEntryFragment.java**

```
public class NewsEntryFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
private static ArrayList<NewsEntry> mNewsEntries = new ArrayList<>();
private int mColumnCount = 1;
private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
Context mContext;

private final String TAG = "MY";

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public NewsEntryFragment() {
}

public interface DataInterface{

    ArrayList<NewsEntry> getNewsEntriesInterface();

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newsentry_list, container, false);

    try {
        ArrayList<NewsEntry> newsEntries = 
((DataInterface)mContext).getNewsEntriesInterface();
        mNewsEntries.addAll(newsEntries);
        Log.i("MY", "onCreateView ArrayList newsEntries.size = "+newsEntries.size());
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerview = (RecyclerView) view;
    MyNewsEntryRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = 
new MyNewsEntryRecyclerViewAdapter(mNewsEntries, mListener);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

**MyNewsEntryRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class MyNewsEntryRecyclerViewAdapter extends
 RecyclerView.Adapter<MyNewsEntryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final List<NewsEntry> mNewsEntry;
private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


public MyNewsEntryRecyclerViewAdapter
(List<NewsEntry> newsEntries, OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener) {
    mNewsEntry = newsEntries;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_newsentry, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mNewsEntry.get(position);
    holder.mIdView.setRadius(26);
    Picasso.get().load(mNewsEntry.get(position)
           .getmThumbnail()).into(holder.mNewsThumbnail);


    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
                // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNewsEntry.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final CardView mIdView;
    public final ImageView mNewsThumbnail;
    public NewsEntry mItem;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mIdView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mNewsThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_thumbnail);
    }


}
```

Comment: What about `populateSpinner()` code ?

Comment: sorry, I attached it to the main post, but it's basically just a method for my spinner, it doesn't have anything to do with my problem :)

Comment: have you checked debugging if your adapter is correctly populated?

Comment: Try to add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` at the end of your `onLoadFinished();` . Also, judging by your explanation, I don't think it is ok to create an adapter every time.. `After that, a new NewsEntryFragment gets created, which, in return, creates a new RecyclerViewAdapter`

Comment: Huge thank you, it works with the `notifyDataSetChanged` Method. :D
Regarding to the adapter: There's a new `RecyclerView` for every new `Fragment` I create. `Fragments` get created with new queries. I don't know if this seen as good practise, but im glad it works as intended right now.